# Eclipse not found lib folder?

Tags: android, eclipse

In my project in my job, I have Eclipse Luna with a Android project, in this project I have lib folder that contain some jar files for example: Gson, Volley, support-v4 etc. 
In my job I did not add these jar files in Build Path and works fine.

So, I taked this project and added in Eclipse Luna in my house because I need works in weekend, but the project can't find the lib folder and I can't undertand why. If in my job its works fine with folder jar and not necessary add Build Path, Why in my house need ?

Answer (score -1):

your jar files have to be either inside a separate  folder called "lib" (configured when you create the project for the first time) or inside another folder that you created after the creation of the project for the first time, in this case you have to add this folder to your build path.